# Shinzo Kakutani theorem about convex body

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, convex-analysis, smooth-manifolds

I'm studying an article by Shinzo Kakutani.

https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968964?origin=crossref

It states that every convex body (a compact convex set with non-empty interior) in 3-dimensional space has a circumscribed cube, i.e. a cube all of whose faces touch the body.
In the proof of the theorem he defines a function $f:S^2\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$,
$O=(0,0,0)$,
For any point $p\in S^2$ consider two suporting hyperplane
to $K$ (parallel to each other) which are perpendicular to the vector $OP$.
Let  $f(p)$ be the vertical distance of these two planes.

I proved that $f$ is a well-defined function, guaranteeing the existence of such planes in the definition but
I can't prove that $f(p)$ is a real-valued continuous function defined on $S^2$.
How to calculate the
$\lim_{q \to p}|f(p)-f(q)|$?

I used law of sines to
triangles formed between segments that minimize the distance between the planes but I was not successful.
I tried to prove an inequality like
$|f(p)-(q)|<\alpha.c(p,q)$

where $\alpha$ is the angle between the vectors  $OP$ and  $OQ$ and $c(p,q)<\infty$ is limited constant.

I would be very grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: What is $K$? The convex body? And that $f$ is real-valued is trivial. You want a proof of **continuity**.

Comment: K is the convex. f is width of convex body K , how can i prove than?